# Como cambiar una cadena de conexión sin necesidad de crear nuevamente el instalador

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto en *C#* y *sql server*, donde la base de datos va a estar en una computadora que actuará como servidor, he leído que para que las otras computadoras "escuchen" esa conexión hay que colocar el nombre de la computadora completo mas la instancia **tcp:NombrePc/NombreInstancia** y abrir su respectivo puerto, antes lo tenia así **tcp:(local)/NombreInstancia** y me salía error al abrir y mi pregunta es, ¿si cada que vaya a instalar el programa en una pc que vaya a actuar como servidor tengo que cambiar la cadena de conexión y volver a crear el instalador o hay otra manera?

Comment: depende de qué tipo de proyecto sea. lo más sencillo, creo yo, sería el tener un archivo de configuración externo del cuál tome tu cadena de conexión, así te limitas a modificar el archivo y asunto arreglado

Comment: @L.Ronquillo había echo la conexión en el app.config y ví que el archivo .exe.config se podía cambiar pero me dice que no hay permiso para modificar ese archivo. No se si tienes algún ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira lo que puedes hacer es crear una cadena de conexion portable es decir en un bloc de notas por ejemplo y lo mandas a llamar desde tu conexion, por ejemplo

```
public string Conectar(){

StreamReader Leer;
string ruta=application.StartupPath;
leer= new StreamReader(ruta+@"\NombreBlocdenotas.txt");
string linea;
linea=leer.ReadLine();
retur linea;
}
```

ojo en el bloc de notas creas la cedena de conexion, esto solo te sirve para que no tengas necesidad de crear nuevamente el setup con cadena distinta si no que la puedas cambiar desde el bloc de notas